# Problem with setup on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: system-installation, 22.04

I am attempting to reinstall Ubuntu 22.04.4. As I have poor vision I am first bringing up Ubuntu from a USB and using settings to configure the environment before re-installing. My first step is to connect to the Internet. This is where my problem occurs. To connect to a network, I must supply the password for the network. Unfortunately, Ubuntu does not let me type the password into the input box in the authentication dialog. I am able to type in most circumstances. Any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "configure the environment before re-installing." When you reinstall, you won't have any of the settings that you set while running from the USB device (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: You do not need to connect to the internet to install Ubuntu

Comment: Are you doing this from the setup screen or did you select "try Ubuntu without installing". I ask because you may be able to select "try Ubuntu without installing" and then click on the network icon on the top bar on your desktop screen. You should be able to connect to a network from there.

Comment: I ran from the try Ubuntu option. The failure comes from this process.

Comment: You can try unplugging the Ethernet cable, and turning off the WiFi software and hardware switches